# Jagged array confusion

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I wanted to make a jagged array **matrices** that would store nine 1d arrays that would represent a matrice of a numbers from 0-9. I didn't wrote all the numbers from zero-nine, but all of them have the same size and the only difference is the position of 1s and 0s. This part was sucessful and once I printed the result of `InitializeMatrices()` i indeed got the result that I wanted. **matrices[0][34]** would print the 35th element of the "zero" matrix, **matrice[1][2]** would print the 3th element of the "one" matrix and so on.

The problem began when inside `DistortMatrices()` I tried to make a copies of matrice (36 copies, where indexes 0-17 would be copies of zero matrix) inside matrixToLearn, so I would modify the single copy of the matrice and not the matrice itself and store the changes insides the matrixToLearn. Sadly it doesn't seems to work the way I imagined. For example

> matrixToLearn[0] = matrices[0]; // it copies the array zero as intended
>
> matrixToLearn[0][34] = 0; //It applies to matrices[0][34] as well as all the 18 copies of matrixToLearn, even if after that i call:
>
> matrixToLearn[17][7] = 0 //it will apply to matrices[0][34], matrixToLearn[0][34] and all the copies will be the same

So it seems that it works as some kind of pointer or smth.

How can I fix it so it would copy the matrices[0] to matrixtoLearn[0-17] and the changes to matrixToLearn[0-17] would apply only to itself and its corresponding index and leave the matrices as it is? Look at ---> **Expected results** under the code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int[] zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine;

    int[][] matrices;
    int[][] matrixToLearn = new int[36][];


    private void InitializeMatrices()
    {
        zero =
        new int[] {
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        };

        //And so on up to nine

        matrices = new int[][]{ zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine};
    }

    //index = 0
    private void DistortMatrices(int index)
    {
        int z = 0;
        for (; z < 18; z++)
        {
            matrixToLearn[z] = matrices[index];
        }
        matrixToLearn[0][34] = 0;
        matrixToLearn[17][7] = 1;
    }
}
```

**Expected results**

```
Expected result

            matrixToLearn[0]
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 0,

            matrixToLearn[17] 
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1,

            matrice[0] 
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1,

How it looks right now:

            matrixToLearn[0]
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 0,

            matrixToLearn[17]
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 0,

            matrices[0]
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
```

**EDIT: It seems to go even further and it modifies the "zero" matrix as well**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrixToLearn[0] = matrices[0];
```

This copies the reference to a nested array. It is just like

```
float[] x = ...;
float[] y = x; //copies the reference, not the object contents
```

I usually use `(float[])myArray.Clone()` for cloning arrays. I make this into a little generic extension method.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense:

Changing:  
    `matrixToLearn[z] = matrices[index];`
to:

`matrixToLearn[z] = (int[]) matrices[index].Clone();`

fixed the problem. At least it seems so after printing all the involved arrays after doing these operations. Just gotta make extra sure but i think it will be the right solution!

Comment: Checked everything a few times and it does work! Thank you very much. The problem is solved.